# Placing proper arrow with texts in Feynman Diagram using tikz

Tags: tikz-feynman

I am trying to place some arrow in a Feynman diagram. Here is code the I have written

```
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]
      \def\leglength{2}
      \begin{feynman}
        \vertex[blob] (m) at (0, 0) {\contour{?}};
        \vertex (a) at (-\leglength,-\leglength){\textcolor{blue}{SM}};
        \vertex (b) at ( \leglength,-\leglength){\textcolor{green}{DM}};
        \vertex (c) at (-\leglength, \leglength){\textcolor{blue}{SM}};
        \vertex (d) at ( \leglength, \leglength){\textcolor{green}{DM}};
        \diagram* {
          (a) -- [fermion,blue,ultra thick]  (m) -- [fermion,blue,ultra thick] (c),
          (b) -- [fermion,green,ultra thick] (m) -- [fermion,green,ultra thick] (d),
        };
      \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I need to place arrows like the image attached here in the given code of Feynman diagram.

[image]

Problem I am facing is placing the arrows along with the texts attached with it. I also want to insert customizable blob. Can anyone guide to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you turn your snippet into a complete example?

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. Do I need to make the question more elaborate and precise?

Comment: I was asking if you could make your code snippet into a complete example, starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`, containing all necessary packages and definitions (but not more), so that we can compile your code without making any modifications or additions.

Comment: Oh OK. Thank You. I am doing that.

Comment: A tip: test the example before posting. You're missing a backslash before `begin{tikzpicture}`, and the `\contour` macro causes an "undefined control sequence" error.

Comment: I have noticed. Lock down is affecting my brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(I think you forgot to test that example, it has no `\documenclass`, and `\contour` is still undefined. But forgive me my petty grievances.)</sub>

You can use the `single arrow` shape from the `shapes.arrows` library to create the big arrows, and (mostly) use a `label` to place the text next to the arrows. There are multiple ways of positioning the arrows, I used the existing `\leglength` macro along with relative positioning.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
       scale=1.25,
       label distance=3mm,
       bigarrow/.style={
         single arrow,
         minimum height=1.7*\leglength cm,
         minimum width=0.3*\leglength cm,
         draw,
         label=#1,
         node contents={}
      }
     ]
      \def\leglength{2}
      \begin{feynman}
        \vertex[blob] (m) at (0, 0) {contour{?}};
        \vertex (a) at (-\leglength,-\leglength){\textcolor{blue}{SM}};
        \vertex (b) at ( \leglength,-\leglength){\textcolor{green}{DM}};
        \vertex (c) at (-\leglength, \leglength){\textcolor{blue}{SM}};
        \vertex (d) at ( \leglength, \leglength){\textcolor{green}{DM}};
        \diagram* {
          (a) -- [fermion,blue,ultra thick]  (m) -- [fermion,blue,ultra thick] (c),
          (b) -- [fermion,green,ultra thick] (m) -- [fermion,green,ultra thick] (d),
        };
      \end{feynman}
       \path (m) +(0,1.2*\leglength) node[bigarrow={above:Collider}];
       \path (m) +(0,-1.2*\leglength) node[bigarrow={below:Indirect detection},shape border rotate=180];
       \path (m) +(-1.2*\leglength,0)
           node[left=5mm,anchor=south,rotate=90] {Direct detection} % I'm too daft to get the label to rotate properly, hence a second node
           node[bigarrow={},rotate=-90];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Will you mind if I cite your name in a publication?

Comment: @AMS Not really necessary ...